# OpenCV cannot read MP4 videos

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, image-processing, ffmpeg

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 to read in some MP4 videos. The program works on Macs and other Linux machines, but for some reason when I compile and run the program it gives me these errors before exiting:

```
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d8a5c0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d8a5c0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d8a5c0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d8a5c0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d8a5c0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d8a5c0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d8a5c0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1d8a5c0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1cf8f40] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1cf8f40] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1cf8f40] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1cf8f40] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1cf8f40] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1cf8f40] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1cf8f40] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x1cf8f40] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
[h264 @ 0x1d0dcc0] missing picture in access unit
```

The main parts of the code that are reading in the files look like this (they're split between some methods so I've included the lines that do all the work to do with opening and reading the frames:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open (input_path);
success = cap.read (data.frames[i]);
```

Does anyone know how I can get my program to correctly read in these videos? I tried to add "cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('H', '2', '6', '4'));" before "cap.open" but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience the simplest solution world be to convert to .avi
It seems to be opencv's fault that it cant process mp4 files as simply as .avi

Comment: Unfortunately I have hundreds of mp4 videos to process which would make it extremely time (and space) consuming to convert them all although you're probably right - if I only had to process a couple more videos without more being made then I would just convert them to .avi.

Comment: how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422569/reading-mp4-go-pro-video-using-opencv

Comment: Cheers! I encountered an issue when I changed to Mac too but found that worked if I explicitly use a flag to link it to ffmpeg.